# How to remap 'Shift & Up/Down arrow keys' to type actual up & down arrows?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I do a lot of typing in Evernote and I really need an 'up arrow' and 'down arrow' instead of typing 'increasing' or 'decreasing'... Ideally pressing Shift and 'Up arrow' would be the best way to get an upward arrow. I've downloaded and tried using KeyRemap4Macbook but I can't work out how to get the up or down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

KeyRemap4MacBook currently [can't insert arbitrary text](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/issues/91). For something like this, I'd recommend using DefaultKeyBinding.dict.

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and enter

```
{ "$\Uf700" = (insertText:, "↑"); "$\Uf701" = (insertText:, "↓"); }
```

<sup>`$` = shift, `\Uf700` = up, `\Uf701` = down, `insertText:` will insert a string at the current cursor location</sup>

Quit and reopen applications for the change to take effect