# terminal.app eats SHIFT key when used with UP and DOWN arrows (but not left or right)

Tags: terminal, keybindings

Using `cat` in `Terminal.app` in order to view the raw codes, I get the following:

```
$ cat
^[[D    # LEFT
^[[1;2D # S-LEFT
^[[C    # RIGHT 
^[[1;2C # S-RIGHT
^[[A    # UP
^[[A    # S-UP
^[[B    # DOWN
^[[B    # S-DOWN
```

where:

- `S` is for the shift key
- `LEFT` is for left arrow
- `RIGHT` is for right arrow
- `UP` is for up arrow
- `DOWN` is for down arrow

Thus, the shift key is ignored in conjunction with the up and down arrows, but not with the left and right arrows.

I don't see anything under `Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > keyboard` that would explain this behaviour (following [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/47353/18566), that is how I solved a similar problem).

I could probably use `DefaultKeybinding.dict` (see [this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136478/279008) for example) but that doesn't explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what there is to "explain".  If you want them to be recognized, define them in your terminal profile.

The canonical list of ANSI keycodes I usually use is here:

https://github.com/timothybasanov/terminal-app-function-keys

```
 ⇧↑ \033[1;2A
 ⇧↓ \033[1;2B
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I think that my misunderstanding is that SHIFT is not a character (it doesn't appear in the ANSII code) but only a function key.  Thus, if there is no action specified in the keyboard profile of Terminal.app, then nothing happens. For example, SHIFT+LELFT and SHIFT-RIGHT do appear in the list.  There is still a question: what is the nature of a function key?